# How to assert a value is a valid key without knowing the object keys at compile-time?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

In TypeScript, is there any way to declare that a variable is a `keyof` some `Record` without knowing what the keys of the `Record` are?

Assume an API response returns a payload of JSON. I want to define a type for the keys of the payload so I can index through the payload and know that the value will not be undefined. Is this possible or do I have to simply check for undefined every time I index the payload object?

Example:

```js
const payload: Record<string, ValidValue> = await myApiCall()

const prop1 = 'a'
const prop2 = 'b'

if (isValidKey(prop1, payload)) {
  const value1 = payload[prop1] // the type of `value1` should evaluate to `ValidValue`
}

const value2 = payload[prop2] // the type of `value2` should evaluate to `ValidValue | undefined`
```

Comment: You can make `isValidKey()` a [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/weBJVN).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Certainly there are other questions in this same vein on Stack Overflow already?

Comment: @jcalz ya, I'm trying to figure out how to make this type guard work as expected. Actually, while typing up a response for you, I tried a new variation and I think I got it to work. I'm gonna submit my own answer.

Comment: I added my answer, but I don't understand why `value1` evaluates to `never`, and doesn't raise a TS error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using a type guard function as well, but not returning `key is keyof MyMap`. Instead, I had a type for the payload object of `Record<string, ValidValue | undefined>` and then the type guard returns `payload is Record<K, ValidValue>` where `K` is the type of the key param.

You can play with it [on TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=100&pln=7&pc=1#code/PTAEGICcFMHMEsD2A7UBlaAXArgB1AMaIAm0AUJgJ67SgBqAhgDbzGNPa0C8oARooibQGqAD6hk2ALa9okUOIDOmSPGSwA3KBCgAZonnQAHgym4hZUgSYMYe7MgKYkqKZQCCueAGFmTABQAlABcoAAKkIhS8IrQADxhDJRMiAzEAHwaZMa4BpigAN4AvmQ64NDIxDAIKOhYeIQk5KVgACrUtMzwDIp6Bo3IAG4V8BUE5FQ04UkpaaA8AErQRJDEccqq6gA09F1szJwKoA6kumrQGVlkRMjKoLgzqcShiclP86AMAO4M8Plunh8fiCZDIugcThcoBi7FYAGloJQ4nDQMZMBViL0NmpYOl-ABrRGhOE7B5vNIvR5pEL3KnEaG9JYrNYk3YsfYcaDpQpkUCgGA4SCoQmUaGoMmzYhZErXFB3XCRXAARg+AHIGKrZbd8grELgAExq3iasjwXSgfwwvYIyj+XXK0l0wKBHl8m53QYHaAqngSp4AbXtSoAutowJgABa0Sa0RDmgAGns5SvjoEUEcQ2CY9OgSewDHRoEwiFA8dhHM4qcAoORkGXu-J56CG310wOK-WhnSR6MdUBx0uN-Wp9OZ7OovMF6Mlst7diHcQnaBnZAXatAA).

```
// Type alias for convenience
type Payload = Record<string, ValidValue | undefined>;

const payload: Payload = await myApiCall()

function isValidKey<K extends string>(key: K, payload: Payload): payload is Record<K, ValidValue> {
  return key in payload;
}

const prop1 = 'a'
const prop2 = 'b'

if (isValidKey(prop1, payload)) {
  const value1 = payload[prop1] // the type of `value1` should evaluate to `ValidValue` ✅
}

const value2 = payload[prop2] // the type of `value2` should evaluate to `ValidValue | undefined` ✅
```

Comment: Nice! You taught me something. I would not have thought to use `Record<string, ValidValue | undefined>`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. This appears to work as expected in the TS playground.

```js
const myMap = [1,2,3].reduce((p, n) => ({ ...p, [Math.random()]: n }), {})

type MyMap = typeof myMap

console.log('myMap', myMap)

function isKnownKey(key: string, thing: MyMap): key is keyof MyMap {
    return Object.keys(thing).includes(key)
}

const knownTypes = ['a', 'b']
const prop1 = Object.keys(myMap)[0]
const prop2 = 'b'

if (isKnownKey(prop1, myMap)) {
    const value1 = myMap[prop1]
    console.log('value1', value1)
}

const value2 = myMap[prop2]
/*
TS Error:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"b"' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  Property 'b' does not exist on type '{}'.(7053)
*/
```

However, one thing is concerning and that I don't understand: `value1` evaluates to type `never`. Yet there's no TS error. What's going on here?